# How can I compare a value from database to python input

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

So I am trying to create a login system kinda, normal python terminal. I made a register function but I am struggling with the login one. I am trying to compare my input to the username and password and when I get that done i will add the id's. But how can I do that, I tried everything.

When I run the code and enter the right details, it is telling me "Login failed, wrong username or password", which means that something is wrong with my if statement.

```
    import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password=""
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

def login():
    mycursor.execute("USE logintest")
    login_username = input("Please enter your username or email: ")
    login_password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    
    check_login = f"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '{login_username}'"
    check_password = f"SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = '{login_password}'"

    mycursor.execute(check_login)
    username_result = mycursor.fetchall()

    mycursor.execute(check_password)
    password_result = mycursor.fetchall()

    passwordr = password_result
    usernamer = username_result

    print(usernamer)
    print(passwordr)

    if login_password == passwordr and login_username == usernamer:
        print("Logged in successfully")
    else: 
        print("Login failed, wrong username or password")
        
        
    
def register():
    mycursor.execute("USE logintest")
    new_username = input("please pick a username: ")
    new_email = input("please enter your email: ")
    new_password = input("please pick a password: ")
    insert_new_user = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    new_user = (new_username, new_email, new_password)
    mycursor.execute(insert_new_user, new_user)
    mydb.commit()
    print("User successfully created! insert id:", mycursor.lastrowid)
    

def options():
    print("1. login")
    print("2. register")
    options = input("please pick 1 or 2: ")
    if "1" in options:
        login()
    elif "2" in options:
        register()
    else: 
        print("please only select 1 or 2")
        options()

options()
```

Comment: Try to explain in more detail what is your program doing instead of what it is supposed to

Comment: @janpeterka i just edited it :)

Comment: `"SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = '{login_password}'"` shouldn't it be `WHERE username = '{login_username}'`? cause this current user password is needed

Comment: one is for username and the other is for the password @sittsering

Comment: I understand the user part but not the password part. username is unique but not the password.

Comment: so do i just make it ```SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '{login_username}'```?

Comment: for example, userA  - 123, user2 - 12 , user3 - 1234. now if u login with userA - 12, it'll sshow successful. It might not be answer to your question, but in future it'll be a problem

Comment: yes i understand that, i will compare ids too later but how can i solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you fetch data from a database in python, it returns a list of the data, and input in python is a string, so in other words, you are comparing a string with a list which will always be false.

Comment: oh, then how can i compare them properly?

Comment: @skep_sickomode  try this `passwordr = password_result[0]   usernamer = username_result[0]`

Comment: it dosent work but i checked the type of usernamer and it says tuple

Comment: since you will be comparing a single user at a time, use mycursor.fetchone() then select the data at index 0

Comment: yeah so select from the tuple the data you want using indexing e.g.: mycursor.fetchone()[0]. Something like that

Comment: but i still got a problem, if i enter a wrong username / password instead of running the else statement it crashes
```raceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\blumi\Desktop\folders\coding\py\vsc\sql\login system.py", line 61, in <module>
    options()
  File "c:\Users\blumi\Desktop\folders\coding\py\vsc\sql\login system.py", line 54, in options
    login()
  File "c:\Users\blumi\Desktop\folders\coding\py\vsc\sql\login system.py", line 19, in login
    username_result = mycursor.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: is means the person with that username or password was not found in your database, you can put the code in if statement or try / except statement to catch these errors

Comment: ok thanks, its alll working now, thanks you all so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

you should create a function for verifying the login details. This is how to verify the login details, it should be inside the function:

```
         try:
        username = input("your username")
        password = input("your password")

        conn = (your connection code);
        result = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE usernameColumnOfYourTable = ? AND passwordColumnOFyourTable = ?", (username, password))
        print("connected to database")
        if (len(result.fetchall()) > 0):
            print("user found")

        else:
            print("user not found")

    except Exception as err:
        print("couldn't connect")
        print("General error :: ", err)
```

Note: ? is the parameter marker for pyodbc module, if you're using mysql connector, replace the ? sign with %s

But if you're using a hashed (salted) password, the format will be a bit different.

Applying this logic to your codes:

```
 def login():
connection = (establish your database connection here)
login_username = input("Please enter your username or email: ")
login_password = input("Please enter your password: ")

result = connection.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",(login_username, login_password) )"

if (len(result.fetchall()) > 0):

    print("Logged in successfully")
else: 
    print("Login failed, wrong username or password")
```